# How to set up windows SDK on Windows XP

Tags: windows, installation

I am trying to develop windows desktop application. I have windows XP in my PC. I am not able to get steps to install it and I am not able to find out if it is possible to set up windows SDK for Windows XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you'll need is a compiler. These come together with the SDK and install it for you. You don't normally install the SDK standalone, because without a compiler/IDE you'll not be able to use it.

Comment: Can i get the complete steps for installation

Comment: Err... No. You'll first need to decide on the programming language you want to use, then you'll need a compiler/IDE for this language and then you can download/buy the given compiler. The installation itself is easy and the same as for any desktop application. The problem is that using it (and writing programs) is what will take a lot of time and experience to get you done. On windows, many people use Microsoft Visual Studio for development. You can download free versions here: http://www.microsoft.com/vstudio.